# Can't create Cassandra table with PartitionKey, PrimaryKey and ClusteringOrder

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I'm trying to create the following Cassandra table using Phantom

```
  object itemId extends StringColumn(this) with PartitionKey[String]
  object anotherItemId extends StringColumn(this) with PrimaryKey[String]
  object similarity extends DoubleColumn(this) with ClusteringOrder[Double] with Descending
```

So I want to be able to get all records by `itemId`. And I want them to be ordered by `similarity`. I set `anotherItemId` as `PrimaryKey` because `itemId, similarity` composite key will not be unique. But I receive the following error:

```
com.websudos.phantom.exceptions.InvalidClusteringKeyException: Table similarities: When using CLUSTERING ORDER all PrimaryKey definitions must become a ClusteringKey definition and specify order.
```

This [example](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/wiki/Indexes#compound-keys) shows that using `PartitionKey`, `PrimaryKey` and `ClusteringOrder` is possible. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error tells you, when you specify a clustering order you need to specify one for every single part of your clustering key. If the example is suggesting otherwise, the example is wrong and I will update it now.

```
  object itemId extends StringColumn(this) with PartitionKey[String]
  object anotherItemId extends StringColumn(this) with ClusteringOrder[String] with Ascending
  object similarity extends DoubleColumn(this) with ClusteringOrder[Double] with Descending
```

Remember, `PRIMARY_KEY = PARTITION_KEYS + CLUSTERING_KEYS`, so all clustering keys, or what phantom calls `PrimaryKey`, need to become `ClusteringOrder` when you want to define ordering.

This is a Cassandra imposed restriction, phantom is just giving you an error faster than Cassandra would.

Comment: thanks for response. I ended up with the same solution except I placed `similarity` before `anotherItemId` as I need rows be ordered by its value